# Different scipy versions give different results for curve_fit

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, least-squares

My coauthor and I are trying to use nonlinear least squares to estimate parameters. Quite surprisingly, we get different results from the identical code. We use curve_fit in the scipy.optimize package.

We are using different scipy versions. Is it possible that the versions caused different results? Or there is something I missed?

Can curve_fit use different search methods? Do curve_fit in different versions use different default parameters?

The scipy versions used are 0.15.1 and 0.16.0 respectively. Sorry that it's hard for me to give reproducible examples, because on my Macbook I only have scipy 0.16.0. Or can someone tell me how to use different versions of scipy on one computer?

Comment: "we get different results ..."  How different are they?  Small differences could could be due to different scipy versions, or even different computer hardware ...

Comment: @mgilson Is it true? I suspect the differences were caused by the versions. But there is no randomness in this optimization process, and we used the same initial conditions.  The differences are big enough to cause some concerns.

Comment: @mgilson There are two arguments in the function. On one computer we got the results 0.95549866, 1.112329567, and on the other we got 1.451327293, 2.361104842

Comment: If you cannot give a reproducible example, you should at least give us the scipy versions.

Comment: @cel The scipy versions are 0.15.1 and 0.16.0  It's hard for me to give reproducible examples, because on my Macbook I only have scipy 0.16.0. Or can someone tell me how to use different versions of scipy on one computer?

Comment: @user3821012 You can use `virtualenv` to create separate, self-contained Python environments.

Comment: Is your problem well posed? In general, multivariate non-linear optimization problems often have a high number of local minimas and are therefore susceptible for numeric instabilities. Hence a different computer (architecture) or software library version could lead to different results. A simple indicator is varying the initial and bounding conditions and check if that leads to different results.

Answer (score 0):

It is always possible that there are improvements/bugs in a new release. If there is a fix between releases you should find it from the release notes: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/release.0.16.0.html .

Also you could use http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html to easily install different versions of SciPy. You can get from https://www.continuum.io/downloads